# connection WiFi p2p android, WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I discover the peers but I can not connect to one of them. I feel that my BroadcastReceiver not getting the WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION because it does not execute what's inside.

connect() :

```
    public void connect(View v) {
    // Picking the first device found on the network.
    WifiP2pDevice device = (WifiP2pDevice) peers.get(0);

    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;


    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            Toast.makeText(MultiActivity.this, "Connect initiated" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(MultiActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

onReceive() :

```
else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Connection state changed!  We should probably do something about
        // that.
        Toast.makeText(activity, "ca marche",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (mManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // We are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP
            mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, connectionListener);
        }

    }
```

Toast "ca marche" never appears on the screen.
Please help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to register your broadcast receiver with the proper IntentFilter.

For example:

1. Create new intent filter: `IntentFilter tmpFilter = new IntentFilter();`
2. Add the actions your interested in: `tmpFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);`
3. Register it with the Broadcast receiver (preferable onResume()): `registerReceiver(p2PBroadcastReceiver, tmpFilter)`

You can find here detailed example:
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Goodluck.

Comment: can we use wifi p2p events on statically registered receiver in manifest? I have registered in manifest but nothing is being recgnised.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
    manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            peerListener.connectionSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            peerListener.connectionFailure();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Connect failed. Retry.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```